# Understanding a definition of randomness

Tags: computability, random

I happened across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness#In_mathematics) definition of randomness in Wikipedia:

> [A]n infinite sequence is random if and only it withstands all recursively enumerable null sets.

What does this mean?

If I recall my elementary Set Theory class correctly, this means that a sequence of numbers is random if at each iteration, the sequence generated is not a member of any set created by any previous iteration of the sequence. Is that a correct (and hopefully coherent) understanding?

Please help me understand this.

Comment: @Peter : A set for which cannot be computed by an algorithm is simply "noncomputable"; noncomputable sets can be very non-random. See my answer below for more detail on the notion of randomness OP is referencing.

Comment: There is no notion of randomness in elementary set theory. There is a technical notion in set theory called a random real, though. But that is to do with forcing, and this is neither the time nor the place for that.

Comment: A better Wikipedia article is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence

Answer (score 3):

This is not a set-theoretic definition of randomness, which is probably why you're having so much trouble. "Recursively enumerable" is a concept from computability theory: a set of finite binary sequences is recursively enumerable if there is a Turing machine (or just a computer program, if you're not familiar with Turing machines) which eventually outputs $1$ when given a string from the set, but never halts when given a string not in the set. The most complicated example is the halting problem: the set of binary sequences which represent computer programs that do not go into infinite loops.

In this context, a "recursively enumerable null set" means a sequence of recursively enumerable sets of finite binary sequences, so that the *measure* of these goes to zero - intuitively, think of it like these sets are telling you what the first few bits of your sequence *might* be, and they're getting progressively more and more specific as you go down the line. The sequence also has to be *uniform* (which just means that you can work out all of the recursively enumerable sets with a single program).

Finally, "withstands" in this context would be better described as "escapes". We've got this sequence of guesses that are getting gradually more specific; a sequence is random if every such sequence of guesses eventually has to commit to something wrong about the sequence.

So, in other words: A sequence is *random* if no program can give information about it that is both reliable and arbitrarily specific.

This all may have been too much to cover in one answer - I'm trying to give you the quick and dirty version here, but to really grasp this notion you need to have the equivalent of an introductory computability course under your belt.

Comment: Your definition excludes recursive sets from being recursively enumerable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, it doesn't. If I have a Turing machine that computes the set, I can simply instruct the machine to go into an infinite loop whenever it would have output a $0$.

Comment: Ah, well, that's also true. Although it sort of misses the mark, I feel. A better formulation would "halts 1 if and only if the sequence/number is in the set". That leaves open not halting at all, or halting with 0.